# Jquery wrap multiple actions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a form validation in jQuery. I have 3 fields and I have to validate them. I have this function

```
function validate(field){
  if(field.val().length === 0){
    field.removeClass().addClass("error");
        field.next().removeClass().addClass("error");
    } 
     else if (plz.val().length != 5) {
      field.removeClass().addClass("error");
      field.next().removeClass().addClass("error");
    }
     else {
     field.removeClass();
     field.next().removeClass();
    }

     return field;
    }
```

I have to check 2 more fields, email and phone number, is there a way I can somehow not repeat the code below to all the `else if` statements?

```
field.removeClass().addClass("error");
field.next().removeClass().addClass("error");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a function to abstract the logic?

```
function handleErrorClass(field) {
  field.removeClass().addClass("error");
  field.next().removeClass().addClass("error");
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
handleErrorClass(field);
```

for each needed field